# Magento2.2.6: When I try to edit configurable product than getting this error, facing this issue with only one product

Tags: configurable-product, admin-panel, magento2.2.6, undefined

I am using Magento2.2.6 and in admin side go to manage product and edit configurable product getting this error below

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /XXX/data/home/256705.XXXXX.com/XXXXX/public_html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/VariationMatrix.php on line 43
```

If any one facing this issue and have you get any solutions reply me.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, we had a configurable product set to use with two configurable attributes.

However, one or more of the simple products that were associated did not have a value for the configurable attribute.

Presumably, the products did have this value at one point but the values were removed after the product had been linked up.

The solution was to populate the simple product attribute values. This means you can then edit the configurable product and remove that configurable attribute from the product if required.

**i hope its very helpful to you**

Comment: please go through this i need this "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284844/magento2-3-0-for-configurable-product-attribute-variation-display-this-type"

Comment: for that issue, please do via jquery remember that ??

Comment: But how to possible it if you can hint code

Comment: do you understand my issue swatch option wise dropdown value showing and after add to cart

Comment: yes, i'm undestand.

Comment: by default wise not working its different not open drop-down automatically swatch color choose showing value in relevant dropdown

Comment: please look at in your local and as soon as reply me