# Magento2.3.0 For configurable product attribute variation display this type

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3, product-page, color-swatches, option

I am using Magento2.3.0 an i want to display swatch color and drop-down color name display this type of and after swatch color first attribute selected automatically color name choose in drop-down after add to cart working on it.if this type of anyone implement please reply me.

below first image display

[image]

second image selected option this type showing

[image]

if anyone know how to achieve this

Comment: get label value which is showing in Colour : Sahara via jquery

Comment: two attribuite create in admin one is for swatch color and second is color name define in drop-down inside